# How to convert index.html to index.php in public folder without breaking things using react?

Tags: php, reactjs

I created a project using react and I want to change the index.html to index.php because I have some data to load. How to achieve this without breaking the react structure ?

I was planning to deploy this to Hostinger and seems like there would be a different setup ?

I tried renaming it to index.php but encountered a lot of error.

Comment: I just did the same on one of my projects and everything worked just fine!

Comment: Can you add the error trace?